# How can I mass save a list of URLs to PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, autohotkey

I have a list of URLs for recipes that I want to save as PDFs before my subscription to the site runs out. The URLS were gathered using Xenu Link Sleuth, which were saved to an Excel spreadsheet, tweaked to be cleaned up, duplicates removed, and exported to a Tab delimited txt file.

A friend wrote an AutoHotKey script that will take the URLs and use the Print to PDF option in Chrome, but there are problems with this. Apart from making my computer unusable while it's running since the script needs to control the mouse, it often stops working correctly by somehow trying to save the same URL twice even though there are no duplicate links, or just not saving anything.

Below is the script that my friend wrote. It seemed to mostly work for him, but for me it will not save anything in this state. After Sleep 7000, I added another Send {Enter} so that the Save button on the Save As dialogue box for saving the PDF would be activated, along with another shorter Sleep.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\CookSpread.txt

{
StringSplit, LineArray, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
  URL := LineArray1

Run, %URL%

Sleep 7000

Click 3407, 241
Sleep 3000
Send {Enter}
Sleep 7000

Send ^{F4}
Sleep 4000
}
```

I made some modifications. One is that I reduced the amount of time inbetween each step (maybe this is the problem). I also added a click to select the nutrition info to be printed with the recipe. You can also see my second Enter near the end.

```
Sleep 6000
Click 1500, 550
Sleep 500
Click 1480, 220
Sleep 3000
Send {Enter}
Sleep 1000
Send {Enter}
Sleep 1000
Send ^{F4}
Sleep 2000
}
```

I would expect this to run through, grab a link from the text file, open it in the browser, move the mouse over the print button (the Click), which opens the Print interface. Then the Save button gets hit with Enter, then the Save button is hit with Enter, the file is saved, and then the current Chrome tab is closed before it starts all over again.

What happens is that it goes fine for 20 or 30 URLs, but then something happens where when it goes to save, it's saying that the file already exists and asks if I want to overwrite it. This windows stays open while the script keeps trying to do the rest of the steps, so nothing else gets done. What ends up happening is hundreds of tabs get opened because the URL is still opened in the browser.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to correct this, or if they know of another method to accomplish this. A stand-alone GUI app or something that can use my login credentials and do this in the background would be ideal as the AutoHotKey script makes my computer unusable while it runs. But if someone could figure out how to get this working that would be more than good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**Replace all**

"**D:\Downloads**" in this code
with the path of the folder the program saves the URLs printed

In the **Print**-settings the "**Destination**" must be "**Save as PDF**"

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

ModernBrowsers := "Chrome_WidgetWin_0,Chrome_WidgetWin_1,MozillaWindowClass"
LegacyBrowsers := "IEFrame,OperaWindowClass"

FileCreateDir, D:\Downloads\Newly created
FileMove, D:\Downloads\*.pdf, D:\Downloads\Newly created\, 1

F1::
If !WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")
    Run, chrome.exe
WinWait, ahk_exe chrome.exe
Sleep, 500
Loop, read, %A_ScriptDir%\CookSpread.txt
{
    StringSplit, LineArray, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
    URL := LineArray1
    Run, chrome.exe "%URL%"
    Sleep, 500
    Loop
    {
        WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
        WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe, , 1
        If !(ErrorLevel)
             break
    }
    Loop
    {
        OutputURL := GetActiveBrowserURL()
        Sleep, 500
        If (OutputURL = "")
             continue
        If (OutputURL = URL)
            break
    }
    Sleep, 500    
    Loop
    {
        WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
        WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe, , 1
        If !(ErrorLevel)
             break
    }
    Send, ^p
    Sleep, 500    
    Loop
    {
        WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
        WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe, , 1
        If !(ErrorLevel)
             break
    }
    Sleep, 300
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 500
    WinWait, Save As ahk_exe chrome.exe   
    Loop
    {
        WinActivate, Save As ahk_exe chrome.exe
        WinWaitActive, Save As ahk_exe chrome.exe, , 1
        If !(ErrorLevel)
        {
             Send, !s
             break
        }
    }
    Sleep, 500
    Loop
    {
        FileMove, D:\Downloads\*.pdf, D:\Downloads\Newly created\, 1
        Sleep, 500
        If !FileExist("D:\Downloads\*.pdf")
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
            WinWaitActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe, , 1
            If !(ErrorLevel)
            {           
                Send, ^w
                break 
            } 
        }   
    }
    Sleep, 500
}
Run D:\Downloads\Newly created
return


; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3702
; Get the URL of the current (active) browser tab

GetActiveBrowserURL(){
    global ModernBrowsers, LegacyBrowsers
    WinGetClass, sClass, A
    If sClass In % ModernBrowsers   ; %
        Return GetBrowserURL_ACC(sClass)
    Else If sClass In % LegacyBrowsers  ; %
        Return GetBrowserURL_DDE(sClass) ; empty string if DDE not supported (or not a browser)
    Else
        Return ""
}

; "GetBrowserURL_DDE" adapted from DDE code by Sean, (AHK_L version by maraskan_user)
; Found at 
; http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/17633-/?p=434518

GetBrowserURL_DDE(sClass) {
    WinGet, sServer, ProcessName, % "ahk_class " sClass     ; %
    StringTrimRight, sServer, sServer, 4
    iCodePage := A_IsUnicode ? 0x04B0 : 0x03EC ; 0x04B0 = CP_WINUNICODE, 0x03EC = CP_WINANSI
    DllCall("DdeInitialize", "UPtrP", idInst, "Uint", 0, "Uint", 0, "Uint", 0)
    hServer := DllCall("DdeCreateStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "Str", sServer, "int", iCodePage)
    hTopic := DllCall("DdeCreateStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "Str", "WWW_GetWindowInfo", "int", iCodePage)
    hItem := DllCall("DdeCreateStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "Str", "0xFFFFFFFF", "int", iCodePage)
    hConv := DllCall("DdeConnect", "UPtr", idInst, "UPtr", hServer, "UPtr", hTopic, "Uint", 0)
    hData := DllCall("DdeClientTransaction", "Uint", 0, "Uint", 0, "UPtr", hConv, "UPtr", hItem, "UInt", 1, "Uint", 0x20B0, "Uint", 10000, "UPtrP", nResult) ; 0x20B0 = XTYP_REQUEST, 10000 = 10s timeout
    sData := DllCall("DdeAccessData", "Uint", hData, "Uint", 0, "Str")
    DllCall("DdeFreeStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "UPtr", hServer)
    DllCall("DdeFreeStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "UPtr", hTopic)
    DllCall("DdeFreeStringHandle", "UPtr", idInst, "UPtr", hItem)
    DllCall("DdeUnaccessData", "UPtr", hData)
    DllCall("DdeFreeDataHandle", "UPtr", hData)
    DllCall("DdeDisconnect", "UPtr", hConv)
    DllCall("DdeUninitialize", "UPtr", idInst)
    csvWindowInfo := StrGet(&sData, "CP0")
    StringSplit, sWindowInfo, csvWindowInfo, `" ;"; comment to avoid a syntax highlighting issue in autohotkey.com/boards
    Return sWindowInfo2
}

GetBrowserURL_ACC(sClass) {
    global nWindow, accAddressBar
    If (nWindow != WinExist("ahk_class " sClass)) ; reuses accAddressBar if it's the same window
    {
        nWindow := WinExist("ahk_class " sClass)
        accAddressBar := GetAddressBar(Acc_ObjectFromWindow(nWindow))
    }
    Try sURL := accAddressBar.accValue(0)
    If (sURL == "") {
        WinGet, nWindows, List, % "ahk_class " sClass ; ; % In case of a nested browser window as in the old CoolNovo (TO DO: check if still needed)
        If (nWindows > 1) {
            accAddressBar := GetAddressBar(Acc_ObjectFromWindow(nWindows2))
            Try sURL := accAddressBar.accValue(0)
        }
    }
    If ((sURL != "") and (SubStr(sURL, 1, 4) != "http")) ; Modern browsers omit "http://"
        sURL := "http://" sURL
    If (sURL == "")
        nWindow := -1 ; Don't remember the window if there is no URL
    Return sURL
}

; "GetAddressBar" based in code by uname
; Found at http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/103178-/?p=637687

GetAddressBar(accObj) {
    Try If ((accObj.accRole(0) == 42) and IsURL(accObj.accValue(0)))
        Return accObj
    Try If ((accObj.accRole(0) == 42) and IsURL("http://" accObj.accValue(0))) ; Modern browsers omit "http://"
        Return accObj
    For nChild, accChild in Acc_Children(accObj)
        If IsObject(accAddressBar := GetAddressBar(accChild))
            Return accAddressBar
}

IsURL(sURL) {
    Return RegExMatch(sURL, "^(?<Protocol>https?|ftp)://(?<Domain>(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w\w+)(?::(?<Port>\d+))?/?(?<Path>(?:[^:/?# ]*/?)+)(?:\?(?<Query>[^#]+)?)?(?:\#(?<Hash>.+)?)?$")
}

; The code below is part of the Acc.ahk Standard Library by Sean (updated by jethrow)
; Found at http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77303-/?p=491516

Acc_Init()
{
    static h
    If Not h
        h:=DllCall("LoadLibrary","Str","oleacc","Ptr")
}
Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hWnd, idObject = 0)
{
    Acc_Init()
    If DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", "Ptr", hWnd, "UInt", idObject&=0xFFFFFFFF, "Ptr", -VarSetCapacity(IID,16)+NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x46000000000000C0:0x719B3800AA000C81,NumPut(idObject==0xFFFFFFF0?0x0000000000020400:0x11CF3C3D618736E0,IID,"Int64"),"Int64"), "Ptr*", pacc)=0
    Return ComObjEnwrap(9,pacc,1)
}
Acc_Query(Acc) {
    Try Return ComObj(9, ComObjQuery(Acc,"{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"), 1)
}
Acc_Children(Acc) {
    If ComObjType(Acc,"Name") != "IAccessible"
        ErrorLevel := "Invalid IAccessible Object"
    Else {
        Acc_Init(), cChildren:=Acc.accChildCount, Children:=[]
        If DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleChildren", "Ptr",ComObjValue(Acc), "Int",0, "Int",cChildren, "Ptr",VarSetCapacity(varChildren,cChildren*(8+2*A_PtrSize),0)*0+&varChildren, "Int*",cChildren)=0 {
            Loop %cChildren%
                i:=(A_Index-1)*(A_PtrSize*2+8)+8, child:=NumGet(varChildren,i), Children.Insert(NumGet(varChildren,i-8)=9?Acc_Query(child):child), NumGet(varChildren,i-8)=9?ObjRelease(child):
            Return Children.MaxIndex()?Children:
        } Else
            ErrorLevel := "AccessibleChildren DllCall Failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: This works A LOT better than what I had, though it seems to stop after 6 or so loops. I don't know if it's because mouse focus is changed to something else, or if it's part of the script. Once I click something back in the browser to manually continue the saving, it starts up again on its own.

Comment: Thanks! I will give the edited version a try when I get home. I assume the latest edit is the one to try. I noticed it was edited several times.

Comment: It works for the most part, but it will get hung up on links that redirect; that's no fault of the script. Each list has over a 1,000 recipes (America's Test Kitchen and it's two sister sites :) ). It was getting hung up on what to do when a file already exists, but I added "Send, !y" to the loop before the "Send, ^w". Either way, it's working way better than the first AHK script I had.